# How to restrict swear word input when using a textbox within Visual Basic

Tags: input, textbox

I have had several ideas yet most of the solutions online only restrict certain keys or only numbers, not full strings.
I want a solution that as soon as a keypress of a swear word has been inputted, VB detects it then disallows it. I have been able to do exact string matching so if a user puts the work F*** in, then it shows an error message, but this would not work if the user decided to put in "F***nugget". It would not be elegant nor time feasible to enter every possible combination of swear words. Thanks in advance for help.

```
If e.KeyChar = "F***" Then
    SelectionTextBoxTeamName.Clear()
    MessageBox.Show("Please choose something else")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 'string contains' function.
If you're writing in **vb.net** try `String`'s [Contains function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx), which is used like this:

```
Dim b As Boolean
b = s1.Contains(s2)
```

If you're **not writing in .net**
try [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264811(v=office.14).aspx) function. You can use it as follows:

```
InStr("find the comma, in the string", ",")
```

**EDIT: after op's comment**

If you want to check several swears you can put them in an array and check for each:

```
Dim swears = {"F***", "S***"}
Dim hasSwears As Boolean = false

For Each swear As String In swears
    If InStr(textBox.Text, swear) > 0 Then
        hasSwears = true
    End If
Next
```

Now you know if there are **any** swears according to `hasSwears`.

Comment: I tried using this, but its not to compare two strings, its to see if text entered in a textbox is a swear word. See below

Comment: you need the text box's value string (i think it's called text property in .net). once you have a string variable you can use some form of contains to find swears in it. for c# it should be smth like: textBox.Text.Contains("F***")

Comment: Arnon its for Visual Basic 2012, i also tried that syntax, 'textbox.text.contains = "F***" however it threw me an error.

Comment: Since you're not using .net: `InStr(textBox.Text, "F***")`

Comment: This works brilliantly, yet what if i wanted to add several swear words on the same line? ... e.g. InStr(textBox.text, 'F***", 'S***')